# Поиск задачников по программированию на питоне, с постепенным ростом сложности

Tags: python-3.x

Доброгов ремени суток, уважаемй форумчане. Я тут первый день, и сразу возник вопрос.
   Я начинающий программист на питоне и возникла проблема. Прохожу уже 4й онлайн курс по питону и заметил у себя особенность в обучении- что бы действительно разобраться в теме, мне нужно прорешать 200-300 однотипных задач но с постепенным усложнением условий, добавлением новых переменных, рост сложности и т.д. Такого задачника, где будет постепенный рост сложности задач я не нашел, где много однотипных заданий для тренировки. А на курсах дается всего лишь пару примеров применения. А по интернетам информация довольно разрозенная и различная по уровням сложности. 
    Можете ли посоветовать на ваш взгляд годные и интересные задачники и сайты для начального обучения? Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: От себя - checkio.org или адаптивный тренажер на stepik.org.

Comment: Спасибо, сохранил